# Eliminate Duplicate Rows based on Two Columns using Awk

Tags: bash, awk

Given this input:

```
#       133        15
KBL  40.385  26.385 1.0000 S
KBL  23.846   9.289 1.0000 P
KBL  40.234  26.385 1.0000 S
#       133         4
KBL  40.234  28.566 1.0000 S
KBL  40.385  28.566 1.0000 S
KBL  23.846  12.032 1.0000 P
```

I wish to remove the duplicate rows, specifically where a value on either column 2 or column 3 is repeated.  In other words, I wish to get this output:

```
#       133        15
KBL  40.385  26.385 1.0000 S
KBL  23.846   9.289 1.0000 P
#       133         4
KBL  40.234  28.566 1.0000 S
KBL  23.846  12.032 1.0000 P
```

I have tried `awk '!a[$0]++' file.xy`. However, that only removes the lines that are fully identical. I'm looking to only remove the lines that have repeated values in either columns two or three.

Using Awk, what would be the best way to remove these duplicate rows? 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you share what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried awk '!a[$0]++' file.xy ; however, that only removes the lines that are fully identical.  I'm looking to only remove the lines that have repeated values in either columns two or three.

Comment: your last row has the duplicate `$2`.  Not sure your spec is consistent with the posted data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the lines that start with # printed, do not want their $2 or $3 values considered in the tests for duplicate values, and only want to eliminate duplicates within each of the separate `#`-line delimited blocks:

```
$ awk '/^#/{print; delete seen; next} !(seen[$2]++ || seen[$3]++)' file
#       133        15
KBL  40.385  26.385 1.0000 S
KBL  23.846   9.289 1.0000 P
#       133         4
KBL  40.234  28.566 1.0000 S
KBL  23.846  12.032 1.0000 P
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the output you require. We need two files for this method:

```
awk '!a[$2]++ || !a[$3]++' file1.txt > file2.txt && awk '!a[$3]++' file2.txt
```

The output produced is:

```
#       133        15
KBL  40.385  26.385 1.0000 S
KBL  23.846   9.289 1.0000 P
#       133         4
KBL  40.234  28.566 1.0000 S
KBL  23.846  12.032 1.0000 P
```

Comment: Not sure this is needed here, but you can pipe one `awk` into another instead of going through a `bash` variable and printing it into a file.  This itself is redundant since the output of the first command can be written to a file directly as well.

Comment: @karakfa Thanks for the info, I think you are right. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I don;t follow the logic that got you to it, but I'm pretty sure your code is equivalent to `awk '(!a[$2]++ || !a[$3]++) && !a[$3]++' file1.txt` and my boolean algebra is a bit rusty but I'm again pretty sure that `(!a[$2]++ || !a[$3]++) && !a[$3]++` is equivalent to just `!a[$3]++`. It also mixes the numeric values on the lines that start with `#` with the other lines which I don't think is what the OP wants and it does the uniqueness test across the whole file instead of separately within each of the `#`-line delimited blocks which again I think isn't what the OP wants.

Comment: @EdMorton You always teach me something new. Yes that is so silly of me. You are 100% right.
My code is not equivalent to `awk '(!a[$2]++ || !a[$3]++) && !a[$3]++' file1.txt`. :)